# phoenix hbase table presplit with multiple split points for the same region

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am using **apachephoenix 4.9.1** and **hbase-1.1.2**.
For prespliting the table i am using following option at the table creation time

**SPLIT ON**(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

```
1) is it possible to split (0&1,2&3,4&5,5&6,6&7,8&9)  like this?

2) i tried merging the regions manually using hbase shell. if i
merge a presplit table to (0&1,2&3,4&5,5&6,6&7,8&9) whether it will
contain the presplit info of both regions?
```

Comment: really cool question - I'm interested in the answer

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to split (0&1,2&3,4&5,5&6,6&7,8&9)  like this?'

Yes, just use SPLIT ON(1,3,5,7,9).

In this case, everything <=1 would go in the first split, <1 and >=3 in the second split, <3 and >=5 in the third split, and so on.

I'm assuming here that having the same key in multiple splits (e.g. key "5" in 4&5, 5&6) was a typo. You can't have the same key in multiple splits.

> 2) i tried merging the regions manually using hbase shell. if i
>   merge a presplit table to (0&1,2&3,4&5,5&6,6&7,8&9) whether it will
>   contain the presplit info of both regions?

Yes, it would.